# Connection from Apache to Tomcat via mod_jk not working

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, mod-jk

I would like to connect apache to tomcat via mod_jk (same machine).
The ajp connector in tomcat is listening on port 8009, the worker settings are:

```
worker.worker1.port=8009
worker.worker1.host=localhost
```

However, the connection fails, here is the mod_jk debug log:

```
[debug] wc_get_name_for_type::jk_worker.c (292): Found worker type 'ajp13'
[debug] init_ws_service::mod_jk.c (1097): Service protocol=HTTP/1.1 method=GET ssl=false host=(null) addr=127.0.0.1 name=localhost port=80 auth=(null) user=(null) laddr=127.0.0.1 raddr=127.0.0.1 uri=/share
[debug] ajp_get_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (3154): acquired connection pool slot=0 after 0 retries
[debug] ajp_marshal_into_msgb::jk_ajp_common.c (626): ajp marshaling done
[debug] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2449): processing worker1 with 2 retries
[debug] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1623): (worker1) all endpoints are disconnected.
[debug] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (485): socket TCP_NODELAY set to On
[debug] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (609): trying to connect socket 560 to 0.0.0.0:0
[info] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (627): connect to 0.0.0.0:0 failed (errno=47)
[info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (995): Failed opening socket to (0.0.0.0:0) (errno=47)
```

Why does mod_jk try to connect to 0.0.0.0:0 and not to 127.0.0.1:8009???

Thank you for your help!
Tobias

Comment: Have you tried using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost in the worker properties? it looks odd to me, though...

Comment: worker.worker1.host=127.0.0.1 gives the same result

Comment: Is this on Windows or Linux?

Comment: its Windows Server, 64bit

Comment: Another option is to use mod_proxy_http. You'll set it up with 1 ProxyPass line.

Comment: I've seen a lot of these reports lately where mod_jk is trying to connect to 0.0.0.0:something. Very strange.

Comment: @TobiasSchittkowski Can you confirm that a downgrade to 1.2.35 fixes this problem for you? Also, please post your *entire* mod_jk configuration.

Comment: @TobiasSchittkowski Would you mind taking a look at http://markmail.org/message/medt4pa4dflqkfnd ? Specifically, Mladen has rolled a release-candidate for mod_jk 1.2.27 which contains a confirmed fix for another "0.0.0.0" issue which may have also fixed yours (other case is in a clustered configuration). Can you try the release-candidate to see if it works for you?

Answer (score 1):

We just had the same problem and resolved it by using an older version of mod_jk (it did not work 1.2.36 and did work with 1.2.35) on Windows Apache 2.2.22 32bit